# Find specific CSS @keyframes rule

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I want to adjust a specific `@keyframes`-rule in my CSS with JavaScript. This all worked pretty well with the following code:

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes changecolor {
    0% { color: red; }
    100% { color: green; }
}
@keyframes changecolor {
    0% { color: red; }
    100% { color: green; }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function getKeyframeRule(ruleName) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets,
        rule, i, x;

    for (i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        if (ss[i].cssRules) {
            // loop through all the rules
            for (x = 0; x < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++x) {
                rule = ss[i].cssRules[x];
                if ((rule.type === window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE || rule.type === window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) && rule.name === ruleName) {
                    return rule;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// find keyframes rule
var rule = getKeyframeRule("changecolor");
console.log(rule.cssText);

// adjust keyframes rule
// ...
```

Since Chrome 43 the browser supports unprefixed CSS animation properties. But my code still returns the prefixed keyframes rule `@-webkit-keyframes changecolor` because it also applies to the condition `if ((rule.type === window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE || rule.type === window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) && rule.name === ruleName) {`.

What's a better way to select the keyframes rule which is actually used by the browser?

Here is the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/tschortsch/zbma3bcp/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `keyframes` rule used is the last to be defined. Therefore, you can loop from the end, instead of from the beginning:

```
for (x = ss[i].cssRules.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    rule = ss[i].cssRules[x];
    if ((rule.type === window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE || rule.type === window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) && rule.name === ruleName) {
        return rule;
    }
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbma3bcp/3/).